# How to create a custom test-network in Hyperledger Fabric 2.x? How to create five peer org in a private channel in test-netork?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

For example, I want to create a private channel of five peer org. How should I configure my test-network?
I've created org3 peerOrganizations using configtx.yaml but it doesn't get a container ID.

Answer (score 1):

reference https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html

You need to perform these steps manually,because the script is not applicable.

this tutorials was base fabric v1.4.2,but I think it also applies to v2.x.

and I have put to  git reposistory https://github.com/iamlzw/five-network.git

you need to clone this reposistory  to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/`

1、Configure configtx.yaml

you need configure `Organizations:` ,`TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis` and `TwoOrgsChannel` part of `Profiles:`，how many organizations you want join in network,then you need to configure how many organizations

reference https://github.com/iamlzw/byfn-with-five-org/blob/master/configtx.yaml

2、Configure crypto-config.yaml

you need configure `PeerOrgs:`,same as above,how many organizations you want join in network,then you need to configure how many organizations.

referene https://github.com/iamlzw/byfn-with-five-org/blob/master/crypto-config.yaml

3、Manually generate the artifacts
generate crypto artifacts

```sh
../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
```

generate orderer genesis block

```sh
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID byfn-sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

4、Create a Channel Configuration Transaction

```sh
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
```

5、Start the network

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml up -d
```

5.1 create and join channel

execute this command in your terminal not in cli container, because I dont start a cli container

so you need configure your `/etc/hosts`

```sh
sudo /etc/hosts

### change 192.168.126.128 to your IP or localhost or 127.0.0.1
192.168.126.128 orderer.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer0.org1.example.com 
192.168.126.128 peer1.org1.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer0.org2.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer1.org2.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer0.org3.example.com 
192.168.126.128 peer1.org3.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer0.org4.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer1.org4.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer0.org5.example.com
192.168.126.128 peer1.org5.example.com
```

**next all steps you can execute script `byfn_five.sh`**

5.1.1 create genesis block

```sh
### export peer0.org1.example.com env

export PATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/config/

export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true

export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051

#### create channel genesis block

peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

#### join channel

peer channel join -b mychannel.block

#### export another peer env and join in channel

# export peer0.org2 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
peer channel join -b mychannel.block

# export peer0.org3 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org3MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:11051
peer channel join -b mychannel.block

# export peer0.org4 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org4MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/Admin@org4.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org4.example.com:13051

peer channel join -b mychannel.block

# export peer0.org5 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org5MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer0.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/users/Admin@org5.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org5.example.com:15051
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

5.1.2 install chaincode

```sh
#install chaincode on peer0.org1
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/

#### export another peer env and install chaincode

# export peer0.org2 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/

# export peer0.org3 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org3MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users/Admin@org3.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:11051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/

# export peer0.org4 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org4MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/users/Admin@org4.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org4.example.com:13051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/

# export peer0.org5 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org5MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer0.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/users/Admin@org5.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org5.example.com:15051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

5.1.3 instantiate chaincode,you need just instantiate chaincode on peer0.org1

```sh
#export peer0.org1 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051

#instantiate chaincode on peer0.org1
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

6、invoke and query

```sh
#export peer0.org1 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'

# export peer0.org5 env
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org5MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer0.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/users/Admin@org5.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org5.example.com:15051

peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'

### invoke use peer0.org5
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/five-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","2"]}'

### query
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
```